# Cannot start Tauri dev server - "beforeDevCommand terminated with a non-zero status code."

Tags: rust, pnpm, tauri

I'm attempting to follow the [guidance](https://tauri.app/v1/guides/getting-started/setup/html-css-js) on creating a Tauri app. I've installed all the prerequisites, using Linux Mint.

I'm trying to learn Rust & React so I want to start a new project. Though I can create a tauri app, I am unable to run the dev server.

I ran 'cargo create-tauri-app' using TypeScript, pnpm and React. I then navigate to the new project folder and run 'pnpm install' with no issues. However, when I attempt to run 'tauri dev' (with cargo or pnpm) I received the following error; "SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word" ..... "Command failed with exit code 1, beforeDevCommand terminated with a non-zero status code"

[image: tauri dev response]

Here is the build section of tauri.conf.json

```
"build": {
    "beforeDevCommand": "pnpm dev",
    "beforeBuildCommand": "pnpm build",
    "devPath": "http://localhost:1420",
    "distDir": "../dist",
    "withGlobalTauri": false
  }
```

I've tried changing beforeDevCommand between npm/pnpm and leaving it blank, and I've found no other posts on google containing the same error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/9582

Comment: Sounds like whatever is running the JavaScript doesn't support top-level `await`. Not sure anything more than that since I'm not very familiar with how Tauri and everything work together, but maybe you should try updating something (?)

Answer (score 1):

maybe try to change your ../src-tauri/tauri.conf.json the "build" section to this:

```
"build": {
    "beforeBuildCommand": "",
    "beforeDevCommand": "",
    "devPath": "../ui",
    "distDir": "../ui",
    "withGlobalTauri": true
},
```

this worked for me.